# Expectation and Probability

Tags: probability

I have been given the following:

If X is a positive random variable with E(X) = 0, find P(X=0).

I am guessing this is 1 but how do i prove this?

---

Answer (score 0):

To show $P(\{ \omega : X(\omega) = 0 \}) =1$, it suffices to show $P(\{ \omega : X(\omega) > 0 \}) = 0$.

**Step 1:** Prove $\{ \omega : X(\omega) > 0 \}) = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \{ \omega : X(\omega) > \frac{1}{n} \})$. What does this tell you about the measure of the left hand side?  What is it bounded by?

**Step 2:** Now, for each $n$, $$P(\{ \omega : X(\omega) > \frac{1}{n} \}))  \leq n\int \limits_{\Omega} X(\omega) \,dP = n \cdot 0 = 0.$$  It is up to you to justify how we got the inequality in this step.

Thus, by steps $1$ and $2$, we have $P(\{ \omega : X(\omega) > 0 \})) = 0$.